# UITabbar programatically select tab and performsegue

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uitabbar, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `UITabbar` and depending on action selected in one Tab I perform programatically the switch to another Tab. That works fine, using:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

This Tab has a `UITableView` and on selecting a row, it pushes to a DetailView. What I am intending is to do this push programatically. So I put in:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];    
    if (delegate.iAbreCotizacion == 1)
    {
        delegate.iAbreCotizacion = 0;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDetailGMMFlex" sender:self];
    }
}
```

It works well, but all `UIControls`, except for the View programmatically loaded, are not enabled. That means I am not able to change Tabs from the `UITabBar`. Also I am not able to switch back from the View to the `UITableView`.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry without more information it is not easy to know what does means *all UI Controls (...) are not enabled*. Which controls? I'm sure you are doing something to disable the controls.

For your problem switching back, maybe you need to embed your `UITableView` into a Navigation Controller or just add a Back Button.

[I created a demo with your explanation who works like a charm](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/TabBarAndSegue).